# Having trouble with localStorage on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, local-storage

I want to store the status of a checkbox with localStorage, so that if it is checked, it will remain checked after you refresh the page. However, there seems to be a problem: the checkbox will always be checked, even if it wasn't.
I checked the localStorage and found that the status is stored correctly, however when you refresh the page the data unconditionally switched to "true".
Here is my code.

function called when checkbox is clicked:

```
  function save_data(box){
          var ls = localStorage;
          if(box.checked == true){
            ls.setItem("checkbox_val","true");
          }
          else{
            ls.setItem("checkbox_val","false");
          }
      }
```

function called when window is loaded:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ls = localStorage;
    console.log(ls);
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("privacy_checkbox");
    if(ls.getItem("checkbox_val") == "true"){
      checkbox.checked = true;
    }
    else{
      checkbox.checked = false;
    }
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: it working for me http://jsbin.com/xinohozaho/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I had some issue with Firefox autocomplete which can perhaps be your problem too.

To prevent FF from autofill forms values, you can add the attribute `autocomplete="off"` on you element or form like this :

```
<form method="post" action="/form"  autocomplete="off">
[...]
</form>
```

See this article for more informations : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: What's your version of Firefox ? This (http://jsfiddle.net/ky30jv8d/) is working for me on `FF42` and `FF Dev Edition 44.0a2`

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the code which is calling save_data(), as per your code it should work fine.
However it seems if the object that you are sending in save_data() might not be having .checked property.